# Where to put my HTTPS files in Cpanel

Tags: php, ssl, https, cpanel

I have read everything I can find through google, but nobody seem to give an understandable answer.

I have a cpanel account, with shared hosting. I am developing a php web application that would be requiring SSL, I have setup my own private key from the cpanel. But I have not been able to find out where to upload files I want to access through https.
I am able to see the following when i go to my https right now

Index of /

```
400.shtml
401.shtml
403.shtml
404.shtml
500.shtml
blog/
cp_errordocument.shtml
ea3_apache_build_htdocs/
moving.page/
suspended.
```

Please can someone kindly give me a step by step guide to what I need to do.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question belongs more to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) than to stackoverflow.

- Use [this guide](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache-cpanel.htm) to install the Certificate
- You may have to upgrade your account so you have your own IP (otherwise SSL doesn't work), contact your provider for more information
- The DocumentRoot for your HTTPS files is the same as for your HTTP files.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS and HTTP is just protocols about connection. It's not affects the files structure.

> https://example.com/file.php

will call same file, as

> http://example.com/file.php